# Convert multiple lines to a line separated by brackets and "|"

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have the following data in multiple lines:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want to convert them to lines separated by "|" and "()":

```
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|10
```

I made a mistake. I'm sorry,I want to convert them to lines separated by "|" and "()":

```
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```

What I have tried is:

```
seq 10 | sed -r 's/(.*)/(\1)/'|paste -sd"|"
```

What's the best unix one-liner to do that?

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: seq 10 | sed -r 's/(.*)/(\1)/'|paste -sd"|"

Comment: Why is the last number without parentheses?

Comment: sorry, Didn't check carefully, the problem has been corrected

Comment: Regarding `What's the best unix one-liner` - asking for a "one-liner" tells us you care more about brevity than clarity, efficiency, robustness, portability, maintainability or any of the other things that actually matter in software, and asking for "the best" is subjective. Both things discourage people from answering and are like to get a question closed (which may explain your current close vote, not mine btw).

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/(&)/;H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n/|/g' file
```

Surround each line by parens.

Append all lines to the hold space except for the first line which replaces the hold space.

Delete all lines except the last.

On the last line, swap to the hold space and replace all newlines by `|`'s.

N.B. When a line is deleted no further commands are invoked and the command cycle begins again. That is why the last two commands are only executed on the last line of the file.

Alternative:

```
sed -z 's/\n$//;s/.*/(&)/mg;y/\n/|/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. This should work in any version of `awk`.

```
awk -v OFS="|" '{val=(val?val OFS:"") "("$0")"} END{print val}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([0-9]+)\n/(\1)|/;ta;s/\|$/\n/' input_file
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple `awk` command:

```bash
awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s|", p} {p="(" $0 ")"} END {print p}' file

(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
sed -z 's/^/(/;s/\n/)|(/g;s/|($//' your_input
```

where `-z` allows you to treat the whole file as a single string with embedded `\n`s.

In detail, the sed script above consists of 3 commands separated by `;`s:

1. `s/^/(/` inserts a `(` at the beginning of the whole file,
2. `s/\n/)|(/g` changes every `\n` to `)|(`;
3. `s/|($//` removes the trailing `|(` resulting from the `\n` at EOF, that is likely in your file since you are on linux.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```bash
$ seq 10 | perl -pe 's/.*/($&)/; s/\n/|/ if !eof'
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```

`s/.*/($&)/` to surround input lines with `()`

`s/\n/|/ if !eof` will change newline to `|` except for the last input line.

---

Here's a solution with `paste` (just for fun):

```bash
$ seq 10 | paste -d'()' /dev/null - /dev/null | paste -sd'|'
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```

Comment: /dev/null - /dev/null    I don't get it

Comment: It can be any empty file. `paste` doesn't support multicharacter delimiter, so using empty input is a workaround. `-` refers to stdin data.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '{printf "%s(%s)", sep, $0; sep="|"} END{print ""}'
(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)|(10)
```